# Display Gamecenter leaderboard on website

Tags: iphone, game-center

Is there currently a way to read GameCenter leaderboard data from the Web?

I'm looking for a read only way to display a leaderboard on a companion website. I do not need to post scores or otherwise manipulate the leaderboard off the device.

I have a feeling the answer is going to be no and I'll need to use OpenFeint's because they have a JSON API available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to find an answer to this as well.

I came across an interesting article [Game Center via Openfeint](http://retrodreamer.com/blog/2010/09/game-center-via-openfeint/)
that discusses using Openfeint and Gamecenter together by using the [new Openfeint SDK](http://www.openfeint.com/developers/ios/game_center/)

Then using their JSON API publish results to the supporting website. I cant see any other way around it and feel this is what we need to do. Not the nicest, but you do end up with a game that sits in both communities.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. This definitely an end run but an interesting approach. File as feature request with Apple and maybe they will open things up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the author of the app and your web host provides PHP and MySQL you could roll your own server-side script to process score submissions and another script to generate a dynamic HTML page to display the scores in any way you like. Many web hosts offer PHP and MySQL for free.

There is no ready made solution that I am aware of. 
To be honest I don't think there is much to gain from doing this, since players already have access to the leaderboard from within the game, and visitors to a website might not care about high-scores of a game they haven't played. Thats just my opinion.